# Python assistance with simple input and random number

Tags: python, random, input, python-3.x

I am trying to get this simple piece of code to run, which iterates a sequence of four random numbers until it matches the four digit number input by the user. I know there are simpler ways to do this, but I'm just wondering as to why this it not working. The program will compile and when it reaches the while check, the screen the terminal just never updates and the program doesn't terminate. thanks

```
import random
attempts = 0
pin = input("Please enter your four digit pin: ")
str_pin1 = str(pin)


while True:
    digit1 = random.randint(0,9)
    digit2 = random.randint(0,9)
    digit3 = random.randint(0,9)
    digit4 = random.randint(0,9)
        digit1 = str(digit1)
        digit2 = str(digit2)
        digit3 = str(digit3)
        digit4 = str(digit4)
    attempts = attempts +1

    if digit1 == str_pin[0] and digit2 == str_pin[1] and digit3 == str_pin[2] and   str_pin[3]:)
        break
print('it took', attempts, 'for random number to find your code')
```

Comment: `input` [returns a string](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) so there is no need to call `str()`

Comment: The lines of code to be repeated in the `while` loop should be indented four (4) spaces.

Comment: They are indented, forgot to do that here

Comment: You are checking that digit2 matches str_pin[3] which does not match the first two conditional checks.

Comment: You have an incomplete conditional statement at the end of your `if` statement.

Comment: At the end of your `if` statement you include a variable `str_print` which is not declared in the posted code.

Comment: Yeah this was a type, I've updated the code now and its still not working, same thing is happening

Comment: If the loop keeps running, that means that your conditions are not being met. Mark Ransom has a suggestion about that. Please consider reading his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14903666/42346

Comment: how do I do this on here? I've got it working now, totally forgot about the str cmp to int for some reason.

Comment: you could use [`pin = int(input())` and compare it as: `if pin == random.randrange(10000)`](http://ideone.com/gS7Ov9)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Except that most PIN systems don't consider "23" and "0023" to be the same PIN…

Comment: @abarnert: Except that validating input (`len(pin) == 4 and set(pin) == digits`) and finding number of random attempts are different tasks.  If you want to be pedantic; `int` accepts other invalid input such as `0x01`, `0b01`, etc.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Even for this problem, using `int` means you have to rewrite the core of your program to change it to handle "4-to-6-digit PINs"; if you stick with strings, you only have to change the random-PIN-generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple typo: you have `digit2` in both the second and third cases of your `if` statement, so unless the `pin` has the same digits in both places it will never match.

In addition a comparison of an integer with a string will never be equal. You need to convert each random digit to a string.

Comment: Yeah thanks for pointing this out, don't know why i was trying to compare a string with a int!

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this:

```
import random
attempts = 0
pin = input("Please enter your four digit pin: ")
guess = ""

while guess != pin:
    guess = str(random.randint(0,10000))
    while len(guess) < 3:
        guess = "0" + guess
    attempts = attempts +1

print('it took', attempts, 'for random number to find your code')
```

Comment: [or even simpler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903563/python-assistance-with-simple-input-and-random-number#comment20905921_14903563)